# .htaccess redirect trouble

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

I'm having trouble with (what should be) a simple .htaccess redirect. I need to changed any url that has "`for_homes`" into "`for_home`".

```
RewriteRule ^for_homes(.*)$ for_home$1 [L,R=301]
```

However when I go to any pages with `for_homes` I get a 404.

---

Rewrite Rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.* 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.* 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 

    #request to index.php 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
    RewriteRule ^for_homes(.*)$ for_home$1 [L,R=301] 
    RewriteRule ^for_business(.*)$ for_businesses$1 [L,R=301] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does `for_homes` always appear at the beginning of the URL? Your regular expression implies it does (`^for_homes`)

Comment: Do you have a `RewriteEngine on` in your code? Rule looks OK!

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
        #request to index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
     RewriteRule ^for_homes(.*)$ for_home$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^for_business(.*)$ for_businesses$1 [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a preceeding rule is rewriting to index.php. In this block here:

```
#request to index.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

### This rule rewrites "for_homes" to "index.php?/for_homes"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 

### These rules never get applied   
RewriteRule ^for_homes(.*)$ for_home$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^for_business(.*)$ for_businesses$1 [L,R=301]
```

So perhaps after the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, add conditions to exclude the later 2 rewrites, So that it looks like this:

```
#request to index.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/for_home(s)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/for_business(es)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^for_homes(.*)$ for_home$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^for_business(.*)$ for_businesses$1 [L,R=301]
```

If it's your intention to have index.php *handle* `for_home` and `for_businesses`, so that when someone enters http://domain.com/for_homes/stuff in their browser's address bar, the browser gets redirected to http://domain.com/for_home/stuff, **then** it gets internally rewritten to `/index.php?/for_home/stuff` so that index.php can handle the request, you simply need to move the 301 redirects *before* the index.php rewrite:

```
### Redirect first
RewriteRule ^for_homes(.*)$ for_home$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^for_business(.*)$ for_businesses$1 [L,R=301] 

#request to index.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are just missing `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^for_homes(.*)$ for_home$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that was there several lines up. There are a few rewrite rules already in place (from the CMS) that work fine. I also made a change to test if my changes were even being noticed.

Comment: @Jeff post the earlier rules too then, one of them may be matching and superceding this one.